# Wix: moving <Upgrade> into <Fragment>

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I'm working on a suite of related applications that all have their own WiX installer. As you can imagine, there's a lot of duplication between these installers, and I'm trying to do something about that. To this end, I've created a WiX Library Project with some `.wxs` files, and I've been trying to shove as much code as possible into these `.wxs` files. Which has worked mostly fine, so far. However, there's one thing that I can't seem to move to a `.wxs`: the `Upgrade` element.

This is my upgrade code:

```
<Upgrade Id="MY-UPGRADE-CODE-GUID">
  <!-- If an older version is found replace it -->
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" Property="OLDERFOUND"
                  Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMaximum="no"/>
  <!-- If the same version is found do nothing (OnlyDetect) -->
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Property="SELFFOUND"
                  Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMinimum="yes"
                  Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMaximum="yes"/>
  <!-- If a newer version is found do nothing (OnlyDetect)  -->
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERFOUND"
                  Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMinimum="no"/>
</Upgrade>

<CustomAction Id="AlreadyUpdated" Error="This version of !(wix.Param.Upgrade.ProductName) is already installed. You will have to uninstall it manually before this installer can continue."/>
<CustomAction Id="NoDowngrade" Error="A newer version of !(wix.Param.Upgrade.ProductName) is already installed. You will have to uninstall that version manually before this installer can continue."/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize"/>
  <!-- If the same version is found execute AlreadyUpdated -->
  <Custom Action="AlreadyUpdated" After="FindRelatedProducts">SELFFOUND</Custom>
  <!-- If a newer version is found execute NoDowngrade -->
  <Custom Action="NoDowngrade" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWERFOUND</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

For `Upgrade/@Id`, I use the same value as for `Product/@UpgradeCode`. (I'm not sure whether that's necessary, or even good practice.) I'd like to put that in a `WixVariable` at some point but for now I'm trying to make it work with literal GUIDs.

I have already moved the `CustomAction`s and the `InstallExecuteSequence` to a `Fragment` in my `.wxs` file. I have defined a `WixVariable` to contain the ProductName, so I can have each app's installer display its own name. This works exactly the way I want and expect.

However, when I move the `Upgrade` element into a `Fragment` (it doesn't matter if it's in the app's `Product.wxs` file or in one of the library `.wxs` files, and it also doesn't matter if the `Fragment` is the same one that contains the `InstallExecuteSequence`), the following problems occur:

- If I first run the old version of the installer, and then the new one with `Upgrade` moved into a separate `Fragment`, but with identical `Product/@Version`, `Product@/UpgradeCode`, and `Upgrade/@Id`, I end up with 2 installs of the same product, which is obviously not what I want.
- If I install the new installer twice, it won't install the second time (which is what I want), but it won't show my error message either.

I would replace the whole thing with a `MajorUpgrade`, were it not for the facts that 1) it doesn't seem to want to give an error message when the same version is installed again, and, more importantly, 2) it's not allowed inside a `Fragment` for some reason, so I'm still stuck with duplication (albeit a lot less than previously).

So ... how can I move my `Upgrade` element into a `.wxs` library without losing the current functionality? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like the contents of the fragment are just not included into the MSI package. You can verify this by opening the resulting MSI in Orca and checking e.g. InstallExecuteSequence table for the presence of e.g. AlreadyUpdated custom action. If the assumption is correct, then you should reference any element from a fragment in your main wxs file. Of course, it should be an element which has its Ref brother, like CustomAction / CustomActionRef. In this case the entire fragment will be included.

Comment: FYI The MajorUpgrade will reduce this code down to one line... http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/major_upgrade.htm http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_majorupgrade.htm

Comment: @caveman_dick I know but as I said, it's not allowed in a `Fragment`, only in a `Product` environment, and therefore not usable in a WiX Library Project. Though now I'm using includes (see the accepted answer), that's no longer a problem...

Comment: True, but I don't really worry about it when it's only one line as it doesn't really clutter the Project file. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [wix Linker documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/light.htm), the linker will follow references between fragments while building a windows installer database. But this means that it will ignore any fragments that *aren't* referenced (directly or indirectly via other fragments) by the product wxs.

This behavior can be quite useful in your scenario, because it allows you to model the dependencies between all your reusable components, and the linker will make sure to include only the ones that are needed for a specific product.

To make sure that your upgrade logic is included, you have two alternatives:

1. Add a dummy [Property](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_property.htm) to your fragment, and reference it with a [PropertyRef](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_propertyref.htm) in your product wxs.
2. Or put your upgrade logic in an [Include](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_include.htm) element, and then instruct the wix preprocessor to include it in your product wxs. See the [Wix Preprocessor](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/preprocessor.htm) documentation for an example.

Comment: I chose alternative #2, because I ran into some more issues, which I could solve with an include file but not a library. I think I'll migrate all my wxs stuff into wxi files, for consistency. Thanks for the suggestion though!